# How to nest groups of array objects based on their values and positions?

Tags: javascript

I have an array that's structured like this:

```
[
  {
    "combinator": "OR"
  },
  {
    "combinator": "AND"
  },
  {
    "combinator": "AND"
  },
  {
    "combinator": "OR"
  },
  {
    "combinator": "AND"
  },
  {
    "combinator": "AND"
  }
]
```

I need to create another array from it that would place all the objects with combinator value of "OR at the top level, and nest all the "AND objects between two "OR" objects into an "OR" object that precedes them, in order to get something like this:

```
[
  {
    "combinator": "OR",
    "subarray": [
      {
        "combinator": "AND"
      },
      {
        "combinator": "AND"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "combinator": "OR",
    "subarray": [
      {
        "combinator": "AND"
      },
      {
        "combinator": "AND"
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

Does anyone know how can this be done?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I tried filtering the array for all the "OR" objects and then I thought about splicing the initial array somehow by comparing it with the or array but I got completely stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following assumes there is always a leading "OR" in the array and groups those that follow until a new "OR" is encountered and repeats

```js
const grouped = data.reduce((a,c)=>{  
   if(c.combinator === 'OR'){    
      a.push({combinator: 'OR', subarray:[]})
   }else{
      a[a.length-1].subarray.push(c)
   }   
   return a;
},[]);

console.log(grouped)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

```html
<script>
const data=[{combinator:"OR"},{combinator:"AND"},{combinator:"AND"},{combinator:"OR"},{combinator:"AND"},{combinator:"AND"}];
</script>
```